# Chrome not printing Google Font

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I have a web site that's using a print style to dictate how the pages look when printing.

We're using a Google font called Lato. The pages are printing fine in all browsers and even some colleagues Chrome browsers print the pages fine. However on my own browser and another colleague's the text seems to be printed in white and some glyphs apprear. It looks like the text is there but just in white as it still prints same number of pages, you can see bullet points, underlines etc.

I changed the font to a websafe Arial with !important on *, body and p selectors for print media type and this did make headers appear but body text still not appearing.

[image: Print Preview]